# Enzyme returns null for prop on shallow rendered react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

### The Issue

I am just getting started with enzyme and react testing. I am trying to get enzyme working with karma and webpack on a trivial react component. My issue is that `prop()` on the wrapper returns null and I am not sure why.

**Greeter.js**

```
import React from 'react';

/*
 * A trivial component we added while trying to get the react testing  working
 * */

export default class Greeter extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: props.initialName };

    this.greeterText = this.greeterText.bind(this);
}

greeterText() {
    return (<p>Hello, {this.state.name}!</p>);
}

render() {
    return (<div className="greeter">
        {this.greeterText()}
    </div>);
  }
}

Greeter.defaultProps = { initialName: "World" };

Greeter.propTypes = {
  initialName: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

**greeter.spec.js**

```
import Greeter from '../../components/test/Greeter';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';


describe("Simple testing with shallow rendering", () => {
  beforeEach(function() {
    let initialName = "joe";
    this.wrapper = shallow(<Greeter initialName={initialName} />);
  });

  it("renders default Greeter", function() {
    console.log(this.wrapper.find(".greeter").text());
    console.log(this.wrapper.debug());
    console.log(this.wrapper.state('name'));
    expect(this.wrapper.state('name')).to.equal("joe");
    expect(this.wrapper.prop('initialName')).to.equal("joe");
   });
 });
```

**Result**

> Simple testing with shallow rendering
>      × renders default Greeter
>        Chrome 50.0.2661 (Windows 10 0.0.0)
>      AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'joe'
>          at Assertion.assertEqual >>(F:/web/forms/node_modules/chai/chai.js:776:12)
>          at Assertion.ctx.(anonymous function) [as equal] (F:web/forms/node_modules/chai/chai.js:4192:25)
>          at Context. (F:web/forms/spec/components/greeter.spec.js:9:2932 <- webpack:///spec/components/greeter.spec.js:18:52)

**Stack**

- react 0.14.8
- karma
- webpack
- enzyme 2.2.0

Comment: what shows when you first log the state?

Comment: LOG: 'Hello, joe!'  
LOG: 'Hello, joe!'  
     
LOG: '<div className="greeter">  
<p>  
Hello,  
joe  
!  
</p>  
</div>'  
LOG: '<div className="greeter">  
<p>  
Hello,  
joe  
!  
</p>  
LOG: '<div className="greeter">  
<p>  
Hello,  
joe  
!  
</p>  
</div>'    
LOG: 'joe'  
LOG: 'joe'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test props passed in like that use `mount` like so:

```
  it('allows us to set props', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Foo bar="baz" />);
    expect(wrapper.props().bar).to.equal("baz");
    wrapper.setProps({ bar: "foo" });
    expect(wrapper.props().bar).to.equal("foo");
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! This did in fact work for me. In what scenario can you check props with shallow? I am puzzled why they included the props call in the documentation for shallow without qualifying its usage...

Comment: It is to check the props passed into child elements but not the props passed into the component itself.  Why would you need to know these anyway?  You passed them in yourself so of course you know what they are?

Comment: `shallow` calls your react component's render method and it's api allows you to query the resulting react elements.  To understand this deeper this is a good read: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html

Comment: @JackAllan I did `.setProps` a bit so needed to know what the current props were. Is this possible?

Comment: @JackAllan one use might be mounting a component created in a closure and trying to check what the prop values bound to it were

Comment: This isn't necessarily wrong, but I wouldn't suggest using `mount` if all you want to do is check the wrapper's root node props, because `mount` takes significantly more processing than `shallow` to power. Check my answer below I believe it is the correct one for a small ask such as OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is `wrapper.instance().props.nameOfProp` to access a shallow wrapper's root node props.

Conceptually, consider you have a component that conditionally runs a Function prop at mount time. That's certainly worth checking, right?