# Using Jest Enzyme Mocking Props and state from one component to other component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I am using Jest for creating mocks and enzyme "mount" for passing props. I have SampleClass.jsx render button. Below is the code.

```
             import React from 'react';
import action from '../../Creator.jsx';

export default class SampleClass extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.startChat = this.startChat.bind(this);
    this.action = action;
}

startChat(e) {
 //Here data is constructed
action.startChat({
         data: data
    })

    this.props.onClickHandle();
  }

   render(){
    return (<Button onClick={this.startChat} > </Button>)
}
}
```

Below is the app.jsx where the SampleClass is used.

```
import SampleClass from  /../../../SampleClass.jsx;
export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor( props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {replyText : ''};
    this.handleChatReplyTextChange = 
    this.handleChatReplyTextChange.bind(this);
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
}

handleChatReplyTextChange(text){
    this.setState( { replyText : text })
}

handleOnClick(){
    this.setState({ replyText: '' });
 }   
render()
{ 
 return (<SampleClass  onClickHandle={this.handleOnClick} text=
{this.state.replyText} inputForStartChat={this.props.inputForPreText}/>);
}
  }
```

I have to do mocking of SampleClasscomponent and I use the below code to mount.

```
         import React from 'react';
 import { shallow , mount, render} from 'enzyme';
 import SampleClass from '../SampleClass';

 describe('Button', () => {

 let startChatComponent;
 let onClickHandle;
 let replyText;
 let inputForPreText;

 beforeEach(() => {

  onClickHandle = jest.fn();    

  startChatComponent = mount(<SampleClass onClickHandle={onClickHandle} />);
});

 it('Button click calls ComponentFetch', () => {

  const startChatComponentFetch = mount(<SampleClass onClickHandle={onClickHandle} replyText={replyText} inputForStartChat={inputForPreText} />);

  button.simulate('click',{ target: { value: 'Name 4' }});
  expect(onClickHandle,replyText,inputForStartChat).toBeCalledWith('Name 4');
});

});
```

I have done the simple example as state in below link but my requirement is the pass the props and state and simlate click handler from one componet to other.

[Enzyme returns null for prop on shallow rendered react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061887/enzyme-returns-null-for-prop-on-shallow-rendered-react-component)

Below are the questions?

1. How to mock replyText and inputForPreText as props which is passed from SampleClass.jsx to app.jsx which renders SampleClass  component.
2. I have only mount the SampleClass component with onClickHandler as an example. Please let me know how to pass replyText and inputForPreText as props   to mount the component.
3. How to mock the SampleClass component which will simulate the call the action.startChat with some smple data.
4. How to change the SetState with some changed data which pass it to component and component updates as the data is changed, but it should simulate by calling 
   action.startChat